# OCaml : Raise an error inside a match with structure

Tags: exception, functional-programming, ocaml, match

In OCaml, I have a list of strings that contains names of towns (Something like "1-New York; 2-London; 3-Paris"). I need to ask the user to type a number (if they want London they have to type 2).
I want to raise an exception message saying that the town is not valid, if the person types for example "4", in the example.
I tried this, but it doesn't work :

`let chosenTown = match int_of_string (input_line stdin) with
                    | x > (length listOfTowns) -> raise (Err "Not a valid town")`

What's the good way to code "if the chosen number is bigger than the length of the list then raise the error" ??

Comment: doesn't work is a vague sentence

Comment: is there another way to limit the user to choose only from the available numbers ? Like if the list has 3 items then the person cannot chose "4" ??

Comment: ok, by "doesn't work" i mean I get : "Error: Syntax error"

Answer (score 1):

Pattern can't contain arbitrary expressions. It can be a constant, a constructor name, record field inside curly braces, list, array, etc.

But patterns can be guarded, e.g.

```
match int_of_string (input_line stding) with
| x when x >= length listOfTowns -> 
 invalid_arg "the number is too large"
| x -> List.nth listOfTowns x
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer, patter matching relies on unification and does not expect assertion (it is not the equivalent of a `switch` in `C` or so).

The idea is that you provide different "shapes" (patterns) that your term (the thing you match on) could have.
For a list for instance:

```
match l with
| e :: e' :: r -> (*...*)
| e :: r       -> (*...*)
| []           -> (*...*)
```

It also had a binding effect, if you pass on, say, `[1]` (a very small list indeed), it won't match `e :: e' :: r`, but will match `e :: r` and then `e = 1` and `r = []`.

---

As ivg said, you can add conditions, as booleans this time, thanks to the keyword `when`.

However, when manipulating lists like this, I would go for a recursive function:

```
let rec find_town n l =
  match l with
  | t :: _ when n = 1 -> t
  | _ :: r            -> find_town (n-1) r
  | []                -> raise (Err "Not a valid town")
```

This is basically writing again `List.nth` but changing the exception that it raises.